# Query for padding a string in SQLite in iOS

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I'm working on iPad app which has SQLiteDB as a backend.

I'm searching for string padding concepts in sqlite queries.

Can any one provide sqlite query for below data.

**Need to fill the empty spaces with the character 'Y', and Need to apply the padding with character 'Y' up to 20 characters.**

**For Example.**

**If Input Column's value String is : YY YN**

**Then Output Column's value String Should be: YYYYNYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY**

Please assume the column name is '**size**' and the table name is '**sizetable**'.

I just need a query which supports on sqlite , No objective-C coding.

Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May I know the reason why i got down votes for my question. Is there any wrong in my question or Am i expecting more from you guys or The way i'm asking is wrong?. Please suggest me as I'm new to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Append enough 'Y' characters to pad out even the shortest possible string;
2. truncate it to 20 characters:

```sql
SELECT substr(size || 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY', 1, 20) FROM sizetable
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the wrong turn in my Question to get down votes.